# Need help capturing javascript prompt and using value to create a new row in a table

Tags: javascript, plsql, oracle-apex

I have an apex application where I want a button to trigger a dynamic action.  The action would be comprised of three parts:
1. Javascript to prompt for some value
2. PL/SQL to insert a row in a table including the value from 1
3. submit page

I can get the prompt to work but when step 2 runs it does the insert using the previous value from #1.  For example if I hit my button twice, the first time I get nothing inserted into that column and the second time I get the value I entered the first time I was prompted.

Javascript action:

```
 $x("P2_REJECT_REASON").value = prompt("Please indicate your reason for rejecting this request", "");
```

PL/SQL action:

```
begin
INSERT INTO PDD_APPROVER(PDD_ID,STATUS,REASON) 
VALUES(:P2_PDD_ID,'REJECT',:P2_REJECT_REASON);  
end;
```

Comment: Missing your `ajax` call. Not enough information here to even guess what might be the problem.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Actually, from an Apex context this is enough info. Dynamic actions are javascript actions defined declaratively in apex. The second action described will perform an ajax call, without the developer having to code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it is always one value behind is because of your page submit. The page submit will set the session state of the item to the submitted value. When your page has rendered again and the dynamic action fires, the session state of the item is still that of the value submitted during the last page submit.

If you want the value of a page item to be available in the PLSQL code of the dynamic action, you need to submit the page item to the session state when the call occurs. Do not forget that session state does not necessarily match the value of the item on the page. The page item is on the actual rendered page on a client, while session state resides in the database on the server. Since PLSQL is code ran on the server, you need to provide the values used.
You can add the item to the "Page items to submit" field of the "Execute PLSQL" action.
[image: dynamic action - execute plsql action settings]

However... Why would you first perform a plsql action and then submit the page? That is totally pointless. It'd be far better to conditionally perform a process on page submit than to first execute a piece of plsql (synchronously even!) and then submit again!

Comment: The "page items to submit" was the trick.  This is my first APEX app so I'm learning as I go.  My use case is that I have a form with buttons that record approvals/rejections.  The rejections prompt for a reason.  Each approval/rejection generates a row in an approval table including the id of the main document.  If I just have the button collect the rejection response and do a submit then on the page submit section I need to determine whether this is an approval/rejection or another submit action.  How is this better?  Not saying it isn't just wanting to learn why.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SheanMcManus Buttons submit the page, but also set a request value. It is then possible to conditionally run a process. Alternatively - there is no need to submit the page when you insert a record when you click a button. The transaction is committed anyway and does not require a page submit. It doesn't seem like you would need both actions with the info provided.